# Why is a protected variable visible at class level?

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility, protected, access-specifier

A `protected` variable is access to any class within a package and only to a subclass that `extends` the base class outside the package.

Why did Java implemented this in this was i.e default within package instead of `private` within package?
This is defeating the whole purpose of having blocking access to your variables.

The definition of protected access modifier in java is that if you define `classA` has a `protected` variable `x` -- then `x` is visible to every class in the same package and it is also visible to any class outside the `package` but `extends classA`. I feel that within the package level it should be `private` instead of default access. I am sure Java might have a good reason behind it, and I want to know what this might be.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: The definition of protected access modifier in java is that if you define classA has a protected variable x -- then x is visible to every class in the same package and it is also visible to any class outside the package but extends classA. I feel that within the package level it should be private instead of default access. I am sure Java might have a good reason behind it, and i want to know what this might be.

Comment: Awesome, put all that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java "package" is a bunch of classes that are (by definition) implemented by the same guy, and (generally) work together. Hiding data from your own package is counterproductive — you're supposed to trust everything in your package, because you wrote it all.

If you really want to absolutely hide a variable from everybody (even other classes within your package), just make it "private".